# Changing "summary" to "full text" in feed options has no effect when visiting my_site.com/feed/

Tags: wordpress

At my_site.com/feed/ only the summary of blog posts shows up. I changed "summary" to "full text" in feed options, to no avail. Any idea why it didn't solve the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the different feed types?

http://example.com/?feed=rss
http://example.com/?feed=rss2
http://example.com/?feed=rdf
http://example.com/?feed=atom

Comment: It all redirects to my_site.com/feed/